# Undo local changes in vscode at specific line with shortcut

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using vscode for programming and I have some local changes in my file.
If a file has local changes, the changed lines will be marked on the left side of the line number gutter as seen on the picture. You can undo those changes by simply clicking on the marks of the respective line.

However, is there a specific shortcut to revert the local change of the line where my cursor is currently located? This is because clicking on the mark is annoying after a while.

[image: example I would like to revert the change in line 55]

Comment: what is the command executed when you click the gutter mark?

Answer (score 16):

1. Choose your code changed
2. Press `Command + Shift + P`
3. Type `revert`, you will see `Git: Revert Selected Ranges`
4. Enter

Comment: Default shortcut is `Ctrl` + `k` then `Ctrl` + `r`.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can also define a key in vscode profile shortcuts.

1. Press `Command + Shift + p`
2. Open keyboard shortcuts
3. [image: List item]

And past the following object into the Array

```json
    {
        "key": "alt+cmd+z",
        "command": "git.revertSelectedRanges",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
```